# python variable output not adding to list

Tags: python, list

I need to store the res values in a list 'a' but it only prints the last value of res.The res values from all the 3 if conditions from the program produces an output as follows:

```
['Keel']
['goodthing']
['Tensa']
['Jees']
['John']
['Mary']
['he']
```

When i wanted to add output to the list 'a' it only prints `['he']` rather than all the output

```
import re
a=[]
with open('qwert.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        res = re.findall(r'(?:Dr[.](\w+))', line)
        if res: 
            a= res
        res = re.findall(r'(?:As (\w+))', line)
        if res:
            a= res
        res = re.findall(r'\w+(?==\w)', line)
        if res:
            a= res

print a
```

Please help me to store all the output in the list 'a'.Answers will be appreciated!

Comment: Why did you think repeatedly re-assigning `a` would cause the original list to change?

Answer (score 3):

Use `a.extend(res)` instead of `a = res`

An example:

```
>>> a=[]
>>> a.extend([1,2])
>>> print a
[1, 2]
>>> a.extend([3,4])
>>> print a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of `a = res` do `a += res`, have same effect like using `list.extend`